# What is the result of arithmetics with mpz variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmp

I am trying to do some arithmetic with gmpy2 in python. Unfortunately I don't
know what are the types of returned values of this arithmetics. For example:

```
x=float(gmpy2.comb(100,50))/gmpy2.comb(200,100)
print x
print isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex))
```

gives me:

```
1.114224180581451e-30
False
```

I couldn't find any helpful information when I Googled a bit.
Is there a way that I can get an object type in python in general?
Otherwise, what is the exact type of this value? Is it an mpz?
And the last question, when I do arithmetic with mpz values and for
example float, will it always cast the type to mpz?

P.S. I don't know if mpz is a correct term I am using here! I would be also happy
if somebody with high reputation adds gmpy to tags in stackoverflow to make them
questions more accessible to the people who know gmpy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `gmpy2` but you can find the type of an object in Python using `x.__class__`.

With new-style classes you can also use `type(x)`.

Comment: Thank you. type(x) works but it returns:
<type 'mpfr'> which doesn't make sense!

Comment: Why not? Looks like you are dividing a `float` by an `mpz` (multiple-precision integer) and getting an `mpfr` (multiple-precision real). I guess, without knowing much about `gmpy` or your program, that you might want to create an `mpfr` instead of a `float` in the numerator: `gmpy2.mpfr(gmpy2.comb(100,50))`.

Comment: So is it the case that I have the same hierarchies of casting as I do for types in python. What I mean is if there is a mpz everything else will be in mpz and if there is mpfr everything else will be in mpfr. Right?

Comment: Looks like it, but I defer to casvh as the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 1):

gmpy2 introduces several new data types: mpz, mpq, mpfr, and mpc. They are analogous to Python's int/long, fractions.Fraction, float and complex types. So division involving an mpz will normally result in an mpfr.

In your example, you create an mpz, convert it to a float, and then divide it by an mpz. When performing the division, gmpy2 converts the float to an mpfr and then performs the division. If you want a float result, you should apply float() to the entire result and not just gmpy2.comb(100,50). Note the differences in the parenthesis.

```
>>> float(gmpy2.comb(100,50))/gmpy2.comb(200,100)
mpfr('1.114224180581451e-30')
>>> float(gmpy2.comb(100,50)/gmpy2.comb(200,100))
1.114224180581451e-30
```

Why the conversion from float to mpfr? The mpfr data type can support much higher precision and has a significantly wider range that a float. As long as the precision of mpfr is greater than or equal to the precision of a float (i.e. 53), then the conversion is lossless.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy and gmpy2.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. What I was trying to figure out is the hierarchies that seems to exist.(That in a mathematical expression every term will casted to the one which has the higher precision even for gmpy types)(correct me if I am wrong)

Yeah but it takes more memory and because I am writing a program with dynamic programming, I have to convert everything at the end to float to save space, thought the calculations are best on very long numbers!